# Unexpected Response from SOAP API

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

So, I'm trying to work with SoapClient in php and I'm having an issue structuring my XML. I'm working with a soap API that's expecting the following XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:app="http://app.whatever.com/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
   <app:WhateverCleanseAddress>
   <app:address>
    <address Address1="9100 Wilshire Blvd" Address2="Ste 900" Address3="" City="Beverly Hills" State="CA" Zip="90212" Country="USA"/>
   </app:address>
   </app:WhateverCleanseAddress>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've done a bunch of testing with soapui and this returns the correct response, but the actual call that I'm making with SoapClient only returns an error. This is what I'm submitting:

```
$addressdata = "<address Address1=\"9100 Wilshire Blvd\" Address2=\"Ste 900\" Address3=\"\" City=\"Beverly Hills\" State=\"CA\" Zip=\"90212\" Country=\"USA\" />";
$wsdl = 'http://www.whatever.com/WhateverWebSSAdapter.asmx?WSDL';

$client = New SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0));

$apiData = array(
"Address" => $addressdata
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($client->WhateverCleanseAddress($apiData));
echo "</pre>";
```

I've trolled the net for a good tutorial for forming these requests but I haven't had any luck finding something that shows a 1:1 relationship showing "If you pass soap client this it will submit this". I used this same technique to work with another api call that worked flawlessly... but here I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you considered using NuSOAP (http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)? It is a free php library that can be used for a SOAP client or server. I've never used the client part of it, but I've used the server part, and it works very well.

Comment: you are passing the XML as a string. SoapClient will likely create a string type out of it, but that is not what you want. Please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php how this normally works.